# Volume of a sphere proof

Tags: integration, spheres

I am trying to proof that $V_{sphere}=\frac{4}{3}{\pi}R^3$.

I think that a sphere should be composed by infinite cylinders with an height that tends to zero and a ray that varies from $0\to R$ but I do not obtain the former equation for the Volume.

I came up with this equation but it's wrong.

$V=2\int_0^R{\pi R^2dr}$

Comment: Please show us what you obtain instead.

Comment: I would like to do it but I do not have any idea of how to write an integral with latex

Comment: One way to do this would be to visualize the ball as a solid formed by revolving the graph of a certain function around the $x$-axis.

Comment: Yes I know that proof

Comment: Use `$\int ...$`

Comment: So based on your idea, each cylinder has tinkness (height) $dh$ and its radius $r(h)$ depends on where it lies on the stack. The radius of each cylinder will be $\sqrt{R^2-h^2}$. Overall you get $\int_0^R \pi (\sqrt{R^2-h^2})^2 dh = \frac23 \pi R^3$. Here I assume only the upper semi-sphere

Comment: I do not know how to write an integaral from 0 to R

Comment: @user154508 if you'll write \int_a^b it will give you the integral from a to b. Another thing: Zubzub answered your question, just don't forget to multiply by 2 because he gave the volume of only half a sphere

Comment: Also, if you write "\pi" instead of "pi" you'll get $\pi$ instead of $pi$.

Comment: @user154508 you have to be careful integrating to get a sphere because your segments have to be consistent.  This exercise is one that trips a lot of people up.  It turns out the most straightforward way to get the right result, is to integrate across concentric layers and take the thickness of them to zero as you take their number to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

The surface of a slice is $\pi$ times its squared radius, and by the implicit formula for the sphere, the squared radius of the slice is the squared radius of the sphere minus the squared altitude.

So in terms of the altitude, the squared radius of the slice follows a downward parabolic curve, the area of which is easily found to be the two thirds of the enclosing rectangle.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prove it is to generalize the method of cylindrical shells to a method of spherical shells. The idea is the same, to take round slices and integrate over them, exploiting a symmetry. Then life is good, since the surface area of a sphere is $4 \pi R^2$, integrating $\int_0^R 4 \pi x^2 dx$ clearly gives the desired formula.

The surface area formula can also be found directly also using integration, by doing the double integral $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi r^2 \sin \theta\  d \theta \  d \phi$$

Which can easily be worked out to give the formula $S = 4 \pi R^2$, which we can then re-integrate. Alternatively, you can do this in one-fell-swoop by just integrating three times all at once.

$$\int_0^R \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi r^2 \sin \theta \  d \theta \ d \phi \ dr$$